# Objective C : How to import huge XML data to Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, core-data

We want to import a huge XML-file (13MB) to Core Data. At the moment, the XML-File includes around 64000 entries, but this number will increase in future.

XML-Structure:

```
<entry name='...' doctype='' last-modified='...' [some more attributes]  />
```

After a lot of research which included the [XMLSchema Sample Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html), [Ray Wenderlich XML Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) and some stackoverflow entries, we didn't found a solution yet.

We first download the XML-File, and afterwards start parsing and insert the data to `CoreData`
Here is our implementation:

```
- (void)importXMLFile:(NSString*)fileName {

  NSInputStream* theStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithFileAtPath:fileName];

  _theParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithStream:theStream];
  _theParser.delegate = self;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    [_theParser parse];
  });    
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {

    Importer* __weak weakSelf = self;

    NSManagedObjectContext* theContext = self.importContext;

    [theContext performBlock:^{

        CustomObject* mo;

        // Create ManagedObject
        // Read values from parsed XML element

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

           // Call a handler, just for information "added object"

        });

        NSError *error = nil;

        if ([theContext hasChanges] && ![theContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } else {
            DLOGError(error);
        }

    }];
  }

}
```

Using this methods, memory usage explodes leading to a crash. The XML file seems to be parsed completely before even one block is being processed by `Core Data`. So the question is:

Is it possible to process parts of the XML file (f.e. 30 entries a time), than save to `CoreData` and after that continue parsing?

Or more commonly asked: How can memory usage be optimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a stream based parser so you don't need to load the whole XML to memory at the same time. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677560/xmlstreamreader-for-objective-c-iphone) or something from github.

You should also batch your save operation. Don't save every individual object, save groups of perhaps 100 objects. If this is inside a tight loop you should have an autorelease pool.

Comment: Does SBJson parse XML? I don't see any mention of that at http://superloopy.io/json-framework/api/3.0/index.html

Comment: thanks for your answers. we solved our issue with a "paused" parser. I ll publish the code below

Answer (score 2):

guess our memory problem occurred with a line we didn't publish, while creating our `ManagedObject`. We had to free the `xmlChar`

Instead of

```
xmlChar *xmlString = xmlTextReaderGetAttribute(reader, (xmlChar*)"someAttribute");
NSString *someAttributeToString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)xmlString];
```

we used

```
xmlChar * nameString = xmlTextReaderGetAttribute(reader, (xmlChar*)"someAttribute");
if (attributeString)
{
    [elementDict setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)attributeString] forKey:@"someAttribute"];
    xmlFree(nameString);
}
```

And we pause our parser after parsing 100elements and wait, till those elements are written to `CoreData`. After that, we parse the next 100 bundle

Parser

```
// Start the data parse
- (void) parse {

    _dictionaryQeue = [NSMutableArray new];

    xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlReaderForMemory([data bytes], [data length], NULL, NULL,
                                                 (XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | XML_PARSE_NOCDATA | XML_PARSE_NOERROR | XML_PARSE_NOWARNING));

    if (!reader) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create xmlTextReader");
        return;
    }

    while (xmlTextReaderRead(reader)) {

        @autoreleasepool {

            while (_isPaused) {

                //[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];

            }

            switch (xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader)) {
                case XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT: {

                    NSMutableDictionary* elementDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];                    

                    //Create Object
                    xmlChar * nameString = xmlTextReaderGetAttribute(reader, (xmlChar*)"name");
                    if (nameString)
                    {
                        [elementDict setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)nameString] forKey:@"name"];

                        xmlFree(nameString);
                    }
                    //...

                    if (self.collectDictionaries) {

                        [_dictionaryQeue addObject:elementDict];
                        NSArray* dictArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_dictionaryQeue];

                        if ([dictArray count] == self.maxCollectedDictionaries) {

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                if (saxDelegate && [(NSObject*)saxDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(SAXDictionaryElements:finished:)]) {

                                    [saxDelegate SAXDictionaryElements:dictArray finished:FALSE];

                                }

                            });

                            [_dictionaryQeue removeAllObjects];

                            _isPaused = TRUE;

                        }

                    }

                    elementDict = nil;

                }

                    break;

                case XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT: {

                    DLOGcomment(@"XML_READER_TYPE_END_ELEMENT");               
                    if (self.collectDictionaries) {

                        NSArray* dictArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_dictionaryQeue];

                        if ([dictArray count] > 0) {

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                if (saxDelegate && [(NSObject*)saxDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(SAXDictionaryElements:finished:)]) {

                                    [saxDelegate SAXDictionaryElements:dictArray finished:TRUE];

                                }

                            });
                            data = nil;
                            [_dictionaryQeue removeAllObjects];
                            _dictionaryQeue = nil;

                        }

                    }
                }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlTextReaderClose(reader);
    xmlFreeTextReader(reader);
    reader = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DOM based parsers are quite convenient (TBXML, TouchXML, KissXML, TinyXML, GDataXML, RaptureXML, etc) especially those with XPATH support.  But, memory becomes an issue as a DOM is created.

I am phasing the same memory constrains, so I started looking at wrappers for the **[Libxml2 XmlTextReader](http://xmlsoft.org/xmlreader.html)** and so far I only found one [**IGXMLReader**](https://github.com/siuying/IGXMLReader)

> IGXMLReader parses an XML document similar to the way a cursor would
>   move. The Reader is given an XML document, and return a node (an
>   IGXMLReader object) to each calls to nextObject.

Example,

```
IGXMLReader* reader = [[IGXMLReader alloc] initWithXMLString:@"<x xmlns:edi='http://ecommerce.example.org/schema'>\
                      <edi:foo>hello</edi:foo>\
                      </x>"];
for (IGXMLReader* node in reader) {
    NSLog(@"node name: %@", node.name);
}
```

This is a different approach to that of the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/ParserArchitecture.html).